# I want to check a data from database and if found then a button will be active if not found then another button will be active in jsp

Tags: hibernate, jsp

For my course project i am writing a code for a website contains jsp by net beans. In a page when user will enter then it will check a data from the database if found then it will show a button if not found then it will show another button. I am using `MySQL` database, `Hibernet ORM` framework. How i can do this ? what would be the code for this ?

Comment: can you post what you have done till now.